# How to put a title on a biplot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, pca

I have created a biplot in matlab

```
biplot = biplot(wcoeff(:,1:2),'Scores',score(:,1:2),'VarLabels',drugsFixed,'ObsLabels',cellLines,'MarkerSize',15)
```

It looks great, but I'd like to add a title.  Adding `'title'` to the biplot function call results in an error.  The 'biplot' object doesn't have any children that look like they might have the title handle in it. Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`title`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html?searchHighlight=title&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) function? It works for me on the biplot example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many plotting functions, I can follow up my call to `biplot` with a call to [`title`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html) to add a title to the current figure.

```
%% Biplot of Coefficients and Scores
% https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/biplot.html#bt_y8xe-2
% Load the sample data.

% Copyright 2015 The MathWorks, Inc.

load carsmall
%%
% Define the variable matrix and delete the rows with missing values.
x = [Acceleration Displacement Horsepower MPG Weight];
x = x(all(~isnan(x),2),:);
%%
% Perform a principal component analysis of the data.
[coefs,score] = pca(zscore(x));
%%
% View the data and the original variables in the space of the first three
% principal components.
vbls = {'Accel','Disp','HP','MPG','Wgt'};
biplot(coefs(:,1:3),'scores',score(:,1:3),'varlabels',vbls);

%Add the title
title('My title');
```

If the correct figure is not current, you can change the current figure by calling [`figure(f)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) where `f` is the figure handle that you want to add the title to.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`biplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/biplot.html) creates a bunch of line objects within the current axes, and only [these name-value pairs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/biplot.html#namevaluepairs) are valid for the function input argument list. The line objects are *children* of the axes object, and it's the axes object that contains the [`'Title'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e54942). If you want to add a title, you'll have to do it with a separate command, such as one of the following:

```
title('Biplot title');
%Or...
hAxes = gca;
hAxes.Title.String = 'Biplot title';
```

Comment: I like that your answer addresses why the title property is modified with a separate command.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that >>title as well as >>xlabel and >>ylabel must be called outside of the actual plot.  I assume the following code would be somewhere in your m-file:

```
biplot(*All of the parameters go in here*)
title('This is a title.')
xlabel('This labels the x-axis.')
ylabel('This labels the y-axis.')
```

[Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html) is MATLAB title documentation if you need it.  I find that MathWorks is very thorough with their documentation.